# Reacting to Keypress

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So, I want to make some simple code with Python on Visual Studio Code where when I press Enter, it registers and adds one to a variable, like...

```
if Enter pressed:
   variable += 1
```

Comment: It will depend on what OS you are using — Python has no portable `get_keypress` function built-in or in one of its standard library. On Windows you can use `msvcrt.getch()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did using the keyboard module:

```py
import keyboard
    
variable = 0
    
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("Enter"):
        variable += 1
        print(variable)
```

---

You may have to download keyboard. For this run this command in your computer's command prompt/terminal:

`py -m pip install keyboard`

---

There is probably a better way to do this using `keyboard.on_press_key()` , as using `is_pressed` adds 1 to variable continuously as long as the key is pressed.

Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
import keyboard
    
variable = 0
print("Please Press Enter key")
def on_press_event(event):
    global variable
    if event.name == "enter":
        variable += 1
        print("pressed count %d times"%variable)
    
keyboard.on_press(on_press_event)
    
while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

To listen to key events using `turtle`:

```py
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Screen()

my_turtle.onkeypress(print('hi'), "a")
my_turtle.listen()
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).